# why element starts rotating only after timer ends

Tags: javascript, css

here's a html p element.
When clicked:

1. background-color is changed to `red` than `yellow`
2. it starts to rotate using css transform, by setting the element class to `refresh-start`

This is done in the click handler `onClickRefresh`.

However changes are reflected only **after** the `timer` is called, ends its operation and return. timer waits 5 sec (5000ms).

I would expect to see the changes immediately, **before** timer is called. that is:

1. rotation starts immediately
2. color changes to **red** than **yellow**

this is not happening. How does it make sense?

```js
function onClickRefresh(el){
    //jquery selector
    let id = "#" + el.id;
    
    //read class 
    const co = (id)=>{ return $(id).attr("class")}

    //current class
    console.log("class before:", co(id));
    
    //setting class - start rotating
    el.className = "refresh-start";
    
    console.log("class after:", co(id));

    //temp color    
    $(id).css("background-color","red");
    
    timer(5000);
    
    $(id).css("background-color","yellow");
}


function timer(ms){
    const d1 = new Date();
    let cont = true;
    while (cont){
        let d2 = new Date();

        cont = (d2-d1 >= ms ? false : true);
    }
}
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.refresh-start {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.refresh-end{
animation-play-state: paused;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="refreshNRList1" class="refresh-end" onclick="onClickRefresh(this)"/>
    text
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer` function is synchronous it blocks the next code until it is completely executed. try asynchronous timer

```js
async function onClickRefresh(el) {
  //jquery selector
  let id = "#" + el.id;

  //read class
  const co = (id) => {
    return $(id).attr("class");
  };

  //current class
  console.log("class before:", co(id));

  //setting class - start rotating
  el.className = "refresh-start";

  console.log("class after:", co(id));

  //temp color
  $(id).css("background-color", "red");
  await timer(5000);
  $(id).css("background-color", "yellow");
}

async function timer(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.refresh-start {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.refresh-end{
animation-play-state: paused;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="refreshNRList1" class="refresh-end" onclick="onClickRefresh(this)"/>
    text
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

```js
setTimeout(
  () => {    
    $(id).css("background-color","yellow");
  }, 
  5000
);
```

This code calls a function after 5000 milliseconds, that changes the background-color to yellow. The rest of your code is executed immediately.

```js
function onClickRefresh(el){
    //jquery selector
    let id = "#" + el.id;
    
    //read class 
    const co = (id)=>{ return $(id).attr("class")}

    //current class
    console.log("class before:", co(id));
    
    //setting class - start rotating
    el.className = "refresh-start";
    
    console.log("class after:", co(id));

    //temp color    
    $(id).css("background-color","red");
    
    setTimeout(
      () => {    
        $(id).css("background-color","yellow");
        }, 
        5000
    );
}
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.refresh-start {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.refresh-end{
animation-play-state: paused;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="refreshNRList1" class="refresh-end" onclick="onClickRefresh(this)"/>
    text
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use `setTimeout()`:

```js
    //remove the "`timer(5000);`" line and the timer function.
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(id).css("background-color","yellow");
    }, 5000)
```

Your problem is in the timer function. HTML/JavaScript/CSS are single-threaded. It means, that if you make something in an infinite loop, everything will stop. You had some kind of infinite loop in your timer function, though it ended at the end on 5 seconds, but in the meanwhile, everything was 'lagged' and the CSS animation couldn't start.
For this reason you have to use this syntax:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    //code...
}, 5000 /*delay in milliseconds*/)
```

Comment: I understand your solution but I still don't get it...I understand `timer()` is a synchronous call, and it suspends the executions of the code **after** the `timer()` call, just like every function. Isn't it? So I would expect the rotation will starts immediately, as it is done before `timer()` is called, then color will change to red, execution will be suspended for 5 sec and than color will be changed  to yellow.  what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code below timer(5000) doesn't execute in 5 second cuz css("background-color", "yellow") execute synchronously. Which means JavaScript all put css effect immediately and just execute the timer and just run the timer in background. If you wanna change the background color from red to yellow in 5 second, you should use "setTimeout". It execute the call back function in it in the time you put.

Here is my solution.

```
function onClickRefresh(el){

    let id = "#" + el.id;   
    const co = (id)=>{ return $(id).attr("class")}
    
    el.className = "refresh-start";
   
    $(id).css("background-color","red");
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(id).css("background-color","yellow");
    }, 5000);
   
}
```

I hope you find an answer :D

Comment: I understand your solution but I don't understand still. You wrote:  _javaScript all put css effect **immediately**_. This is actually my point. the rotation is set before `timer()` execution. so why it is happening only after timer is returned.? `timer()` can be any long operation function,  in this case it is just loop doing nothing. But I do not understand why code being executed before `timer()` takes affect only after.

Comment: because when JavaScript Engine meet up timer function in run time, it moves timer to background and then Browser watch the timer in the background and when time you set is up. Browser put the timer function into call stack and it executed! The other codes executes synchronously in run time which means they are moved to call stack right away. :D This is the reason. If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D